# Showing/hiding content from FB fans on my own site

Tags: facebook-like

So I'm adding the 'like' button to my site and I've got it to display *"Thank you for liking example.com"* and *"You seemed to have unliked example.com"* using edge.create;

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=('Thank you for liking example.com');
}
);
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
    function(response) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=('You seemed to have unliked example.com');
}
```

);

However this method only works when the button is clicked. If a visitor comes to my site and has already liked *example.com* I would like to show them a message without them having to click anything.

I know this is possible to do on a facebook page but what about on my own site.  Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Certainly possible using FB.getLoginStatus

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Keep in mind that this refers to a user being logged in to your app and / or Facebook. If someone is not logged in to Facebook, they will of course return FALSE and thus your message should reflect to have them connect OR login.